# Why is AI so underutilized in Altered Carbon?

Tags: altered-carbon

AIs seem *ridiculously* powerful. In the time it takes to wink, Poe is able to integrate the entire field of psychosurgery (a presumably complex topic) into his knowledge base. If AIs are this powerful, and so plentiful as to be used as cheap hotels and brothels, why do we see so little of them? Why are they not controlling everything?

Comment: I think that there is too little information in the series (I haven't read the books), but the people seem to be very prejudiced against AIs (for example, those who visit Kovacs at the Raven, when they find out that it is run by an AI).

Comment: The AIs *hate* humans. Maybe that's why. Remember how the other AIs mock Poe being working with humans calling him *almost human* (which was kind of an insult.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the books you get stuff that is clearly AI driven, but AIs don't really exist as characters. The only one I can remember offhand that even gets a name is the Hendrix, and that's something of a special case since it owns itself.

The author (Richard Morgan) is really gritty, and really into exploring the darker ends of human nature. I honestly just don't think AI is very interesting to him, so while it exists, it's almost always aloof and impersonal (or dysfunctionally insane). I'd expect the show to change that up due to the public interest in AI.

Comment: Do humans hate AI in the books? While this explains that it's not really a subject interesting to the author, it doesn't really explain why the humans hate AI.

Comment: @phantom42 I think it's more like "deeply distrust". They're mostly used as tools. The Hendrix is allowed to exist, and even allowed to be heavily armed, but no one wants to patronize it because it's AI run. There are references to "corporate wars" and the AI's having the ability to "upgrade to artificial intelligence status" which I assume means a legal personhood distinct from some other kind of AI.